# Как изменить формат с.kts на.kt?

Tags: intellij-idea

Подскажите уже замучился. Я только начал изучение Kotlin, и столкнулся с проблемой, как поменять формат файла в языке програмирования Kotlin с.kts на .kt. Пользуюсь Intellij idea.

Comment: это не формат, а расширение

Answer (score 0):

Правой кнопкой на файле → Refactor → Rename file.